# Is there a purrr-shortcut to address the list argument and not its elements?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

If I do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(a = 1:7, b = sample(c(1, NA), 7, replace = TRUE))

d %>%
  mutate(isanymissing = pmap_lgl(list(a, b), ~any(is.na(list(.x, .y))))) %>% # would prefer not to use .x, .y or ..1, ..2 etc
  mutate(isanymissing2 = pmap_lgl(list(a, b), ~any(is.na(.)))) # not working because . == .x == ..1
```

Is there a shortcut to retrieve the complete argument list?

Comment: Are you looking for `d %>%
 mutate(isanymissing = pmap_lgl(across(c(a, b)), ~ any(is.na(c(...)))))`?

Comment: That's exactly it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr::rowwise` and `c_across`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

d <- tibble(a = 1:7,
            b = sample(c(1, NA), 7, replace = TRUE),
            c = sample(c(1, NA), 7, replace = TRUE))

d %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(isanymissing = any(is.na(c_across())))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       a     b     c isanymissing
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>       
#> 1     1     1    NA TRUE        
#> 2     2     1     1 FALSE       
#> 3     3     1     1 FALSE       
#> 4     4    NA    NA TRUE        
#> 5     5     1    NA TRUE        
#> 6     6    NA    NA TRUE        
#> 7     7    NA     1 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Since `rowwise` is not really performant an alternative is `rowSums` together with a data selecting function, here I just use  `cur_data()` to get all of the data, but any `across()` expression without a function would do fine to narrow down the selection.

```r
d %>% 
  mutate(isanymissing = as.logical(rowSums(is.na(cur_data()))))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>       a     b     c isanymissing
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>       
#> 1     1     1    NA TRUE        
#> 2     2     1     1 FALSE       
#> 3     3     1     1 FALSE       
#> 4     4    NA    NA TRUE        
#> 5     5     1    NA TRUE        
#> 6     6    NA    NA TRUE        
#> 7     7    NA     1 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: There is also the `if_any()` option since `dplyr 1.0.4`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `if_any` as suggested by @tmfmnk.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% mutate(isanymissing = if_any(c(a, b), is.na))
#To consider all the columns just specifying .fns is enough 
#d %>% mutate(isanymissing = if_any(.fns = is.na))

#     a     b isanymissing
#  <int> <dbl> <lgl>       
#1     1     1 FALSE       
#2     2    NA TRUE        
#3     3    NA TRUE        
#4     4     1 FALSE       
#5     5    NA TRUE        
#6     6     1 FALSE       
#7     7    NA TRUE
```

Comment: That is definitely the most straightforward answer